# Advice for graphic tablet for math

Tags: gm.general-mathematics

With the current Coronavirus disease (COVID-19), many of us had to switch all our activity to full online mode.

I am wondering whether some of you had the chance to use graphic tablets. I am looking in particular for advice regarding the best model of graphic tablet for math (in particular, for research, giving online seminars, teaching, etc).

I am not looking for expensive tablets with a screen (such as ipad or similar), but simple, possibly not too expensive, graphic tablet.

Comment: Wacom intuos is perhaps the standard one? I'm using one for my teaching this semester.

Comment: There are better forums for this question. Academia and Math Educators are two, and there may be hardware recommendation forums also on StackExchange.  I won't vote it down, but some of the community may find it too far off the scope of this forum.  Gerhard "Every Question Has Its Place" Paseman, 2020.04.24.

Comment: I think that the main point is to practise.  Writing is very slow and untidy at first, but improves a bit with time.

Comment: you might want to consider an analogue solution: a white board which you place in front of your web cam when you give a seminar or lecture.

Comment: You can have a look at this older question (it is rather old and it is closed - but perhaps you can find there some useful information): [Best tablet computer for mathematics](https://mathoverflow.net/q/37425). This is a slightly different question, but some users mentioned what they use: [Tools for long-distance collaboration](https://mathoverflow.net/q/49384). (Again, this comes with the warning that the information there might be dated.)